# How to enable JS and SCSS sourcemaps with SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I've set up a sveltekit project with scss support locally.
But all the generated JS and CSS is inline.

How to generate a `bundle.js` and `bundle.css` with sourcemaps at development time?

**svelte.config.js**  ( SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.144 )

```
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

const config = {
    kit: {
        target: '#svelte'
    },
    preprocess: preprocess({
        scss: {
            includePaths: ['src'],
            prependData: `@import 'src/style/_config.scss';`
        },
        sourceMap: true,
    }),
    compilerOptions: {
        dev: !production
    }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [vite-plugin-svelte FAQs](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/faq.md), global styles should be imported with your JavaScript in order to improve dev startup time and take advantage of Vite's style processing.

In my case, I added this to the script tag on my __layout.svelte file:

```js
import '../style/global.scss'
```

Previously, I had been importing it in the way they said specifically not to do it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**

Put SCSS files in `/static/scss` and generate `style.css`. In my case with a file watcher in phpStorm.

Reference it in `/src/routes/__layout.svelte` like this

```
<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
</svelte:head>
```

In devtools scss files are shown next to a style, but they have nothing to do with the specific style. Sucks

Comment: you can also separate your scss files from the generated CSS by using `savePath` if you're using `vscode-live-sass-compiler` ( https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/faqs.md )